# emacs set-quit-char ASCII character

Tags: emacs

When I run emacs with `emacs -nw` i.e. terminal mode, I get the following error message (which I don't in graphical mode):

`error: QUIT must be an ASCII character`

The source of the problem is the following line in my `init.el`:

`(set-quit-char (kbd "M-s"))`

How can I make this work? Basically I want `ALT+s` to behave like `ESC` in Emacs (I'm using Evil).

Answer (score 0):

Like the error emssage says, the quit character must be an ASCII character, which by definition rules out anything except "traditional" control characters (including DEL) and printable characters.

For me, `(kbd "M-s")` returns `[134217843]` while the maximum ASCII character is `[127]`.

You are not saying on which platform you are, but most modern graphical environments offer multiple ways to remap characters outside of Emacs, so that's probably where you should look.